# How to disable SQL injection possibility in a simple form?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

I have this comment form where the only inputs are a name and a textarea for a comment.

My question is: how can I be sure that there is no way to use SQL injection in my code? I found a couple of guides for this, but I am not sure how to make them work with my code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $pvm = date("F j, Y"); 
    $postId = $_GET["post"]; 
    $lahettaja = $_POST['name']; 
    $kommentti = $_POST['comment'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO kommentti (post_id,kommentti_pvm,kommentti,lahettaja) VALUES (:post,:kommentti_pvm,:kommentti,:lahettaja)"; 
    $kysely = $yhteys->prepare($sql); 
    $kysely->bindParam("post", $postId); 
    $kysely->bindParam("kommentti_pvm", $pvm); 
    $kysely->bindParam("kommentti", $kommentti); 
    $kysely->bindParam("lahettaja", $lahettaja); 
    $kysely->execute(); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Refer links like   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already secure against SQL injection. The only way to secure against it is to use prepared statements with proper parameterization. That is, use prepared statements with a parameter for *every single thing* that could contain user input. You're doing that, so you're in good shape.

Please note: this does *not* mean you can ever treat the data as "clean" or safe. You cannot, for example, pull it from the database and just `echo` it. Doing so opens you up to a type of attack called XSS, or Cross-Site Scripting (technically, in this case, Reflected XSS).

For more information and to learn more, see:

- [OWASP PHP Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet)
- [OWASP SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Okay thank you very much! I really thought that i need add something to check forms or something like that. Great to know that i am doing it right.

Comment: @Frostbch Glad to help!

Comment: @Ed Cottrell how about sanitizing POST data?

Comment: @unixmiah what about it? Proper sanitization is very difficult and very error-prone compared to proper use of prepared statements with parameterization. The latter is the gold standard for preventing SQL injection because it makes SQLi attacks literally impossible.

Comment: @Ed Cottrell, I agree. External payload into any form is unpredictable therefore proper sanitation is very difficult.